# How to have separate plugins for different worlds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How to get plugins separated by worlds? I want the faction plugin in 2 worlds 1 survival and 2 faction. How can I have it separately like in server minebuilder with different player lists for different worlds.

Answer (score 1):

What's BungeeCord?

> BungeeCord is a useful software written in-house by the team at SpigotMC. It acts as a proxy between the player's client and the connected Minecraft servers. End-users of BungeeCord see no difference between it and a normal Minecraft server.

Where can I download it?

> [In their CI Server](http://ci.md-5.net/job/BungeeCord/)

Why is it useful?

Putting it very simple, users see only one server (the BungeeCord proxy), but behind the scenes the proxy is reconnecting them to different servers (for ex. using a custom command, entering a waterfall, etc).  You can have different plugins per server and even different servers in the same network (Bukkit, Spigot, Cauldron..)

For more info: [Wiki](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/bungeecord/)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only way you can do that is with separate servers using different ports. If you are using [Spigot](https://www.spigotmc.org) I recommend having a 'hub' server and connect them with [Bungeecord](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/1-7-2-1-8-bungeecord.392/). Good luck with the server!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [perworldplugins](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/perworldplugins-unofficial-update-version.6454/), or use BungeeCord.

Comment: could you maybe add a tad of explanation about them?