# Is it possible to have a Minecraft server with multiple worlds, some of which are modded?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods, minecraft-bukkit

I'm using the [Multiverse family of server-side mods](https://github.com/Multiverse) on my [Minecraft Paper](https://papermc.io/) (self-hosted) Java edition server. I want to configure my server so that some worlds are Vanilla while others are modded. For example, I'd like to have an aviation world that requires players to have the [Immersive Aircraft client-side mod](https://github.com/Luke100000/ImmersiveAircraft) installed in order to join it. Players should be able to join the vanilla worlds on the server using both Vanilla Minecraft and Minecraft modded with Immersive Aircraft, but they should not be able to use the Immersive Aircraft functionality in the vanilla worlds. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Surely the Immersive Aircraft mod won't work on the vanilla server? It's a client+server mod, so they shouldn't be able to do anything with it.

Comment: More than that. They can't even join it. If the server has forge and some mod(s) installed, it prevents a vanilla user to join the server, if nothing has changed since 2020.

Comment: @Skye-AT Most people use Fabric or Quilt, now - Forge is an expensive modloader. I don't believe they have the functionality to kick a player if they don't have the exactly correct mods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have separate plugins for different worlds?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229054/how-to-have-separate-plugins-for-different-worlds)

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you wouldn't be able to host multiple Minecraft worlds with different sets of mods on the same server instance, but you could have a hub server without any mods and a proxy service like BungeeCord that allows players to jump to different server instances (like is done for large server networks like Hypixel), but synchronizing inventories and gluing everything together would likely be difficult.

TL;DR: you would need to have the worlds on separate servers, probably with a central hub server to pick which one to play on.